# io.fabric8 plugin generates kubernetes and openshift yaml

Tags: java, fabric8, fabric8-maven-plugin

io.fabric8 generates kubernetes and openshift yaml when i include targetDir configuration

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <targetDir>${basedir}/fabric8/</targetDir>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

by default it goes to goes to `target/fabric8/deployment.yaml` i want it to go to `{basedir}/fabric8/` without it generating some extra extra folders and files, just `/deployment.yaml`, this is the command i ran `mvn fabric8:resource`

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Fabric8 team. Fabric8 Maven Plugin has an option `fabric8.targetDir` with which you can override default target directory. Here is how it should work for your use case:

```
~/work/repos/fmp-demo-project : $ mkdir fabric8
~/work/repos/fmp-demo-project : $ mvn fabric8:resource -Dfabric8.targetDir="./fabric8"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< meetup:random-generator >-----------------------
[INFO] Building random-generator 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- fabric8-maven-plugin:4.3.1:resource (default-cli) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] F8: Using Container image name of namespace: rokumar
[INFO] F8: Running generator spring-boot
[INFO] F8: spring-boot: Using Container image fabric8/s2i-java:2.3 as base / builder
[INFO] F8: fmp-controller: Adding a default Deployment
[INFO] F8: fmp-service: Adding a default service 'random-generator' with ports [8080]
[INFO] F8: f8-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding readiness probe on port 8080, path='//health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 10 seconds
[INFO] F8: f8-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding liveness probe on port 8080, path='//health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 180 seconds
[INFO] F8: fmp-revision-history: Adding revision history limit to 2
[INFO] F8: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/fmp-demo-project/fabric8/kubernetes/random-generator-service.yml resource
[INFO] F8: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/fmp-demo-project/fabric8/kubernetes/random-generator-deployment.yml resource
[INFO] F8: fmp-controller: Adding a default DeploymentConfig
[INFO] F8: fmp-service: Adding a default service 'random-generator' with ports [8080]
[INFO] F8: f8-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding readiness probe on port 8080, path='//health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 10 seconds
[INFO] F8: f8-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding liveness probe on port 8080, path='//health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 180 seconds
[INFO] F8: fmp-revision-history: Adding revision history limit to 2
[INFO] F8: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/fmp-demo-project/fabric8/openshift/random-generator-deploymentconfig.yml resource
[INFO] F8: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/fmp-demo-project/fabric8/openshift/random-generator-service.yml resource
[INFO] F8: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/fmp-demo-project/fabric8/openshift/random-generator-route.yml resource
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.127 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-08T12:37:50+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/work/repos/fmp-demo-project : $ ls fabric8/
kubernetes  kubernetes.yml  openshift  openshift.yml
~/work/repos/fmp-demo-project : $ ls fabric8/kubernetes
random-generator-deployment.yml  random-generator-service.yml
```

Unfortunately, Fabric8 Maven Plugin generates resource descriptors for both Kubernetes and Openshift. In case of Kubernetes also, it generates a default `Service`, if you want to disable it, you can configure plugin like this to disable Service Enricher:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                   <enricher>
                     <excludes>
                       <exclude>fmp-service</exclude>
                     </excludes>
                   </enricher>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This way `Service` won't be generated during the resource generation phase and you would be left with `Deployment` only. Here is a run after the plugin configuration:

```
"/work/repos/fmp-demo-project : $ mvn fabric8:resource -Dfabric8.targetDir="./fabric8 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< meetup:random-generator >-----------------------
[INFO] Building random-generator 0.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- fabric8-maven-plugin:4.3.1:resource (default-cli) @ random-generator ---
[INFO] F8: Using Container image name of namespace: rokumar
[INFO] F8: Running generator spring-boot
[INFO] F8: spring-boot: Using Container image fabric8/s2i-java:2.3 as base / builder
[INFO] F8: fmp-controller: Adding a default Deployment
[INFO] F8: f8-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding readiness probe on port 8080, path='/actuator/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 10 seconds
[INFO] F8: f8-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding liveness probe on port 8080, path='/actuator/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 180 seconds
[INFO] F8: fmp-revision-history: Adding revision history limit to 2
[INFO] F8: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/fmp-demo-project/fabric8/kubernetes/random-generator-deployment.yml resource
[INFO] F8: fmp-controller: Adding a default DeploymentConfig
[INFO] F8: f8-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding readiness probe on port 8080, path='/actuator/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 10 seconds
[INFO] F8: f8-healthcheck-spring-boot: Adding liveness probe on port 8080, path='/actuator/health', scheme='HTTP', with initial delay 180 seconds
[INFO] F8: fmp-revision-history: Adding revision history limit to 2
[INFO] F8: validating /home/rohaan/work/repos/fmp-demo-project/fabric8/openshift/random-generator-deploymentconfig.yml resource
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  6.598 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-08T14:20:52+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/work/repos/fmp-demo-project : $ ls fabric8/
kubernetes  kubernetes.yml  openshift  openshift.yml
~/work/repos/fmp-demo-project : $ ls fabric8/kubernetes
random-generator-deployment.yml
```

We have been refactoring/rebranding FMP into two different plugins, you can find it here: [Eclipse Jkube](https://github.com/eclipse/jkube), it has two plugins - [Kubernetes Maven Plugin](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jkube/k8s-maven-plugin/0.1.0/maven-plugin) and [Openshift Maven Plugin](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jkube/oc-maven-plugin/0.1.0/maven-plugin). They only generate Kubernetes or Openshift manifests respectively. That way you can only generate Kubernetes resources which seem to be fitting your current use case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: if you do a  mvn fabric8:resource it generates deployment.yaml file only without the other descriptors,  only if you don't have the <targetDir> in your configuration. once you start putting that or -Dfabric8.targetDir u get the descriptors, which im trying to avoid

Comment: so if you can check under target folder in a case where you did not specify which directory you want it to go. the folders generated are fabric8/deployment and classes/kubernetes ./openshift . so im only looking for fabric8/deployment which i defined under src/main/fabric8/deployment.yml so it gets copied to target

Comment: but once you define your own custom directory the fabric8/deployments.yml get left out

Comment: @muzijack: Fabric8 Maven Plugin always generates resource manifests for both Kubernetes and Openshift. If you want kubernetes specific resources only then you might want to try [Kubernetes Maven Plugin](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.eclipse.jkube/k8s-maven-plugin/0.1.0/maven-plugin). However, by default it generates both `Deployment` and `Service`

Comment: my point is theres one file missing my custom deployment.yml file that doesn't get  copied over

Comment: Have you checked whether your Custom `deployment.yml` fragment is merged into final `Deployment`. If you have provided it in `src/main/fabric8` directory

Comment: the resource fragment isn't copied by plugin, but it's merged into the final generated manifest

Comment: i want to show you through an email of what i'm experiencing, i want to share screenshots. please share your email address if you don't mind.

Comment: rohaan@redhat.com